# Слетел перевод описания знаков Диктор, Усилитель, Публицист

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, знаки

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Share a link to a post later visited by 25 unique IP addresses.
- Share a link to a post later visited by 300 unique IP addresses.
- Share a link to a post later visited by 1000 unique IP addresses.

В традусёре строки [вроде как переведены](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=Share%20a%20link%20to%20a%20post%20later%20visited%20by), но что-то не так...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С новой ревизией (`rev 2020.1.3.35706`) появились переводы.

Answer (score 2):

Это потому что в старых текстах был "вопрос", а в новых - "сообщение".

Comment: Нет, это потому что после этих переделок они не добавили новые строки в Трансифекс :D

Comment: Как так? Старые же были?

Comment: Старые были. А новые строки не добавили.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica я делал перевод не так давно. Но сборка новая, как я понимаю, теперь только в январе будет.